# Debian 9.4.0 (Stretch) with LXQt - anyone experienced the same issues?

Tags: debian, lxde, freeze, icons, lxqt

I tried to install **Debian Stretch** (9.4.0) together with desktop environment **LXQt**.

Hereby I installed a raw and clean system without any additional packages first and then set the recommended and suggested packages to `0` via file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10noinstall-recommends`.

Afterwards I installed the following (basic) packages via CLI:

`xserver-xorg-core`
`lxqt-core`
`lightdm`

---

1. After reboot into the fresh system first problem detected was the fact that my screen freezed during input of log-in data into `lightdm`. Hereby neither keyboard nor mouse pointer showed any reaction. This problem could be solved by installing the additional package `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`. Now log-in does not freeze anymore and will succeed.
2. Second problem was the issue that most of the graphical desktop environment icons are not getting displayed. Therefore I installed the package `lxqt-qtplugin`, but I could only reach the whole amount of icons when installing the additional icon theme package `lxde-icon-theme`. This by default integrated icon-theme `adwaita-qt5` seems to have some problems I guess?
3. Third problem is the issue that common users (except root) do not have permissions to log-out, reboot, shutdown etc. the system. As a normal user clicking on the related buttons in the start menue does not have any effect. I am not yet sure how to fix this issue?

---

Did anyone of you experience similar issues? This did not appear on only one machine, the exactly same things happened when installing this combination into a VM. Maybe LXQt is more in a late beta state than fully reliable at present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first problem of freezing screen can be solved by installing the package `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`
2. Second problem could be solved by switching the icon theme to standard gnome theme, then it worked fine
3. Third problem was solved by installing the package `lxqt-policykit` which will install `policykit-1` as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

I use LXQt.

My install is normally

> Standard system utilities

then

> apt install xorg sudo chromium pulseaudio

and

> sudo apt-get install lxde-core

I haven't tried just xserver-xorg-core

Interestingly he Manjaro site talks about using LXQt modules instead of LXQt-core

> lxqt-config lxqt-panel lxqt-policykit lxqt-qtplugin lxqt-session lxqt-sudo pcmanfm-qt

It says

> The following LXQt packages are not as important, install them when necessary. If you have doubts about the necessity of a package, install it:
>
> lxqt-about lxqt-admin lxqt-globalkeys lxqt-notificationd lxqt-openssh-askpass lxqt-powermanagement lxqt-runner

There is also the idea that LXQt does not have a Windows Manager of its own and others can be used instead. I always install Openbox - although I never boot log into Openbox. e.g. https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/wiki/ConfigWindowManagers

If I need to add apps I tend towards Qt applications https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=List_of_Qt_Applications and, althought I don't have to, I tend towards lightweight applications https://harbhag.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/best-lightweight-applications-for-linux/ (old but good).